# How do I open a new window (shell) from command line in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, putty

I'm working with a tool right now that requires me to putty to a remote host, login, run a series of commands to start an engine, open a new window (and login again) to start a different engine, then open a third window (and again, login) to actually use the tool (leaving the engines running in those first two windows). I'd like to write a shell script to automate the process so that I could just open one window, type "sh whatever.sh" and be off and running, without physically opening the new windows and logging in again. However, I can't find a command to get me from one window to the next. Any thoughts?

Comment: don't really understand... howabout using using ssh to execute cmd on remote machine: `ssh root@www 'ps -ef | grep apache | grep -v grep | wc -l'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just background the first processes by adding an ampersand (`&`) to the command line or pressing `Ctrl+Z` when it is running (and then enter `bg` to let the process continue, more information about that with `jobs`).

If that's not enough, you can create virtual shells with [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).

If you've redirected X (i.e. you can access GUIs over ssh), you can also just start a new window by executing your favorite (GUI) console program, like `xterm`, `konsole`, `gnome-terminal`, etc.

Comment: @Fredrik Updated and included in the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Are you familiar with jobs on linux?

```
nohup whatever_1.sh &
nohup whatever_2.sh &
nohup whatever_3.sh &
```

Or perhaps screen would be of use here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/25301/job-control-and-ssh

See also, nohup:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

Answer (score 3):

The `bash` command opens a Bourne-again shell (bash) session.

Answer (score 2):

Try typing in "konsole". That should open a new bash window and set the focus to it.

Comment: This works, but unfortunately doesn't open a Terminal window, but rather another application.

Answer (score 2):

On my Ubuntu 18 I just type the command:

```
gnome-terminal
```

and a new shell opens... I don't like the above answers because `xterm` and `konsole` most likely not already be installed.

Comment: Is there a way to execute commands in new terminal launch by above command ? By writing some shell files ?

Answer (score 0):

Shell script on target machine cannot be aware of putty windows on client machine.
Consider using Screen : http://www.gnu.org/s/screen/ - it is clean and powerful way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need command line window then write:

```
$ xterm
# new window started
```

If you need python in new window:

```
$xterm python
#now a window will shown with python shell
```

Answer (score 0):

Another nice option from Xfce's terminal:

```
xfce4-terminal
```